# the transposition super operator for non-square matrix products...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The following matrix product of squares matrices written in superoperator formalism looks like:
$$
AB=A\cdot 1\cdot B \rightarrow \operatorname{vec}(A\cdot 1\cdot B) = \left( B^T \otimes A \right)\operatorname{vec}(1)
$$
For the transpose we get:
$$
\left( AB \right)^T =\left( A\cdot 1\cdot B \right)^T = B^T\cdot 1 \cdot A^T \rightarrow 
\operatorname{vec}(\left( A\cdot 1\cdot B \right)^T)=\left( A \otimes B^T \right)\operatorname{vec}(1)
$$
Now, there is already a transposition superator acting *on single matrices* $\hat T$ by flipping (i.e. permuting) elements across the diagonal.
For the transposition super operator *for the matrix product* $\hat T_\Pi$, we conclude that
$$
\operatorname{vec}(\left( A B \right)^T)=
\left( A \otimes B^T \right)\operatorname{vec}(1)=
\hat T \left( A^T \otimes B \right)\operatorname{vec}(1)=
\hat T \cdot \operatorname{SWAP} \left( B \otimes A^T \right)\operatorname{vec}(1)=\\
\hat T \cdot \operatorname{SWAP} \, \operatorname{vec}(A B)
$$

($\operatorname{SWAP}$ swaps the two parts of the Kronecker product and is also a permutation matrix; $SWAP$ and $\hat T$ even commute...)

> How does this change when the matrices are not square anymore?

I'm looking for the matrix representation of the transposition super operator for non-square matrix products...

Comment: I don't understand your question, but vectorised matrix transpose is in general represented by the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) $K^{(m,n)}$, so that $K^{(m,n)}\operatorname{vec}(A)=\operatorname{vec}(A^T)$ for every $m\times n$ matrix $A$. In your case, if $A$ is $m\times p$ and $B$ is $p\times n$, then $AB$ is $m\times n$ and hence $\operatorname{vec}((AB)^T)=K^{(m,n)}\operatorname{vec}(AB)$.